# NSPredicate based on count of children's children

Tags: iphone, core-data, nspredicate

OK, so I have a data structure set up in core data.

Imagine this set up...

Department - can have many - MiddleManagers - can have many - Employees

Department is one entity with a one-to-many relationship with Middle Manager.
Middle Manager is an entity with a one-to-many relationship with Employee.
Employee is an entity on the bottom of the chain.

A MiddleManager does not need to have any Employees.

I'd like to create an NSPredicate that filters Departments so that only Departments with at least one Employee are returned.

i.e. something like...

```
[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"middleManagers.employees.@count != 0];
```

But I can't find the right syntax to create this.

Can someone point me in the right direction please?

Thanks very much.

Comment: In the end I engineered the connections as they weren't as concrete as the example given.  Would still be interested to find out if this is possible though.